# How does one algebraically find the total number of intersections between $\sin(x)$ and a linear equation?

Tags: functions, trigonometry

Take the function $f(x) = \dfrac{x}{8}$ and $\sin(x)$. By plotting, we can see that the graphs intersect at 7 distinct points, indicated by the grey dots. However, how would one approach such a problem algebraically? There seems to be no useful way to isolate the $x$ variable in a manner that would let us solve the problem.

[image]

Comment: Isn't it possible to look at the domain on which the line has $y$ values between $-1$ and $1$ and then determine the number of periods that fit into the domain together with the fact that the line intersects the sine function on the end points of the specific domain? I know that it is not algebraic, but it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

At $x=\dfrac{5\pi}{2}$, compare the *y*-values of $y=\dfrac{x}{8}$ and $y=\sin{x}$:

$\dfrac{\frac{5\pi}{2}}{8}<\dfrac{5(3.2)}{16}=\sin{\frac{5\pi}{2}}$. So there are at least $7$ intersections.

If $x=3\pi$ then $\dfrac{x}{8}=\dfrac{3\pi}{8}>1$, and $1$ is the maximum value of $\sin{x}$. So for $x\ge 3\pi$ there are no intersections.

Therefore there are exactly $7$ intersections.